# Change the value of the private member in the class designed by singleton pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Today I have a question about this code.

```
class Engine
{
    static Engine* getInstance()
    {
        return instance = (instance == NULL) ? new Engine() : instance;
    }
    SDL_Renderer* getRenderer() {
        return mRenderer;
    }
    bool init();
    bool Clean();
    bool Quit();

    void Update();
    void Render();
    void Events();

    SDL_Renderer* getRenderer()
    {
        return mRenderer;
    }
private:
    Engine();
    static Engine* instance;
    SDL_Renderer *mRenderer;
};

Engine* Engine::instance = NULL;
```

If I want to change the value of mRenderer as like a global variable, I must write this code

```
void render()
{
  SDL_RenderCopy(Engine::GetInstance()->getRenderer(),NULL,NULL);
}
```

So I don't know how the mRenderer change are.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't understand the question (if there is any?). If you want to change `mRenderer`, then return it by-reference instead of by-value.

Comment: Also the singleton pattern you used has two problems: 1. It is not thread-safe and 2. it will never destruct the `Engine` object. Instead you can use a local static `Engine` variable (not a pointer) inside `getInstance` and return that (by-reference or by-pointer). This way both problems are solved.

Comment: @user17732522 Can you explain the local static `Engine` variable ( not a pointer) ? I just wanna use the mRenderer variable in another library as like a global variable.

Comment: `static Engine& getInstance() { static Engine engine; return engine; }`

Comment: There's actually no question asked here.   But, if you want a less complicated way of changing the `mRenderer` member, add a member function to your class that allows changing it.   You might also consider adding a member function to retrieve the value. Apply access control (`public`, `protected`, `private`) depending on what other code in your program has a valid need to call those member functions.